# Improving Conversion of Array for Reflection Invocation

Tags: java, reflection, type-conversion

I have three arrays (in the same size):

1. `JSONArray jsonArr` which contains many strings.
2. `Class<?> classArr[]` which contains the parameter types.
3. `Object objArr[]` which contains nothing yet (but we'll make it full, I promise)

I need to convert each of the Strings in **jsonArr** to the type from the same index in **classArr** and put the resulted object in the appropriate index in **objArr**.

For example:

```
Array \ index |  1      |   2     |   3     |  4
--------------+---------+---------+---------+-------
jsonArr       | "1"     | "false" | "false" | "2"
classArr      | int     | boolean | String  | char
```

Should result in:

```
objArr        | 1       | false   | "false" | 2
```

I currently use the following method (in a loop for every object) to convert the parameters and create `objArray`:

```
if (classArr[i].equals(int.class))
    objArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(jsonArr.get(i));
else if (classArr[i].equals(boolean.class))
    objArr[i] = Boolean.parseBoolean(jsonArr.get(i));
....
```

This method works just fine for me, but I wonder - **is there a better way to convert the JSONArray to the types I have in list, or I have no better option than the `if-else` approach?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to use the object type capabilities of JSON.  Rather than specifying JSON arrays of all Strings, define the values as numbers, boolean, etc...  By doing so, the JSON library you are using (I'm assuming Java API from json.org), will be able to automatically convert the values to an appropriate definition.

Here's an example:

```
// JSON String: [1, false, "false", "2"] rather than ["1", "false", "false", "2"]
String jsonEx = "[1,false,\"false\",\"2\"]";
// convert to JSONArray 
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonEx);

// print out values and types
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    Object o = array.get(i);
    System.out.printf("%-8s\t:%s\n", o,o.getClass());
}
```

If you run this code, you will get the following output:

```
1           :class java.lang.Integer
false       :class java.lang.Boolean
false       :class java.lang.String
2           :class java.lang.String
```

As you can see, the library correctly converted all of the data types except for the expected Character.  The reason being that JSON does not have a way to define a character type vs a standard String.  If you can get around this limitation, then this approach should make your application much simpler and easier to maintain.

Another benefit to this approach is that you can use it during direct conversion between JSON strings and Java objects containing Object array attributes.

Comment: Thank you, I used to work so much with only-strings-in-json-string that I absolutely forgot about that. While in the project I met this problem it doesn't matter anymore - you reminded me an important point. Thanks again!